# Is there a way to move row to the selected row in UITableView on image click not on row selection

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

iam building an application in which iam showing the 5 small images in a single row of the UITable view cell. i want to make selection of row on each image clicked not on the selection of row .

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return 160;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"simpsons"];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"simpsons"] autorelease];
    }
    //cell.textLabel.text  = [theSimpsons objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    //NSString *imageName = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d.png", indexPath.row];
    //cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];    

    image1= [[UIImageView  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(5.0,10.0,78, 74)];    
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image1];
    image1.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"0.png"];

    image2= [[UIImageView  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80.0,10.0,78, 74)];   
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image2];
    image2.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"1.png"];

    image3= [[UIImageView  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(170.0,10.0,78, 74)];  
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image3];
    image3.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"2.png"];

    image4= [[UIImageView  alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(240.0,10.0,78, 74)];  
    [cell.contentView addSubview:image4];
    image4.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"3.png"];
    return cell;
 }
```

i want on each image selection only a new row will we opened not on row click ?????

Answer (score 0):

Instad of using UIImageView.Use UIButton.In Custom Style..And Place Image In UIButton Background,So Finally Your Image Will Appear And When You Click On Button You TableRow Is Not Selected.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
    UIImage *Image=[UIImage imageNamed:@"QuickSearchImage.png"];

    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
        UIColor *txtCol=[UIColor clearColor];
    UIColor *ButtonTextCol=[UIColor whiteColor];
    NSString *FontName=@"verdana";
    int FontSize=12;
    CGRect frame ;

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    NSArray *subviews = [[NSArray alloc] initWithArray:cell.contentView.subviews];
    for (UIView *subview in subviews) {
        [subview removeFromSuperview];
    }
    [subviews release];
    cell=nil;

    if(cell == nil)
    {
        CGRect cellRectangle;
        cellRectangle = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, 1024, 200);
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithFrame:cellRectangle reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];

        UIButton *button ;

        frame =  CGRectMake(XOFFSET, YOFFSET, COLWIDTH, COLHEIGHT);
        button = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
        //[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonPressedAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [button setTag:1000];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:button];
        [button release];



        }
    }

    UIButton *BtnCol = (UIButton *)[cell viewWithTag:COLTAG];
    [BtnCol setTag:COLTAG];
    [BtnCol setTitle:[ArrCol objectAtIndex:IntIndex] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [BtnCol setTitleColor:ButtonTextCol forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [BtnCol setBackgroundImage:Image forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    BtnCol.titleLabel.font=[UIFont fontWithName:FontName size:FontSize];

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Sure.

1: you can custom a cell with a Button(show your image and clickable) and other controls.
Then set the tag of each button in a cell.

2: In the IBAction event of each button,  record the tag and use delegate to select relevant row.